# Swift: what is the right way to split up a [String] resulting in a [[String]] with a given subarray size?

Tags: ios, swift, algorithm

Starting with a large [String] and a given subarray size, what is the best way I could go about splitting up this array into smaller arrays? (The last array will be smaller than the given subarray size).

**Concrete example:**

> Split up ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7"] with max split size 2
>
> The code would produce [["1","2"],["3","4"],["5","6"],["7"]]

Obviously I could do this a little more manually, but I feel like in swift something like map() or reduce() may do what I want really beautifully.

Comment: On what basis would you want to do the split? Given you are talking about "page size", the font and size must be important. Why are you trying to do this yourself rather than letting the OS do the text layout?

Comment: What do you mean by page size?

Comment: @GaryMakin sorry, updated now. It's just a set split size, i.e split the array into smaller arrays of max size 100.

Comment: @Jordan, as fun as these are, this isn't really what SO is for - you might want to pose these questions in the #swift-lang IRC channel.

Comment: I asked almost the same question while searching for a swift equivalent of Ruby's `each_cons` function https://stackoverflow.com/q/39756309/78336

Comment: See the SwifterSwift project's `Array.group(by:)` function: https://github.com/SwifterSwift/SwifterSwift/blob/master/Sources/Extensions/SwiftStdlib/ArrayExtensions.swift

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I wouldn't call it beautiful, but here's a method using `map`:

```
let numbers = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7"]
let splitSize = 2
let chunks = numbers.startIndex.stride(to: numbers.count, by: splitSize).map {
  numbers[$0 ..< $0.advancedBy(splitSize, limit: numbers.endIndex)]
}
```

The `stride(to:by:)` method gives you the indices for the first element of each chunk, so you can map those indices to a slice of the source array using `advancedBy(distance:limit:)`.

A more "functional" approach would simply be to recurse over the array, like so:

```
func chunkArray<T>(s: [T], splitSize: Int) -> [[T]] {
    if countElements(s) <= splitSize {
        return [s]
    } else {
        return [Array<T>(s[0..<splitSize])] + chunkArray(Array<T>(s[splitSize..<s.count]), splitSize)
    }
}
```

Comment: Swift 2.0 let chunks = stride(from: 0, to: numbers.count, by: splitSize).map({ numbers[$0..<advance($0, splitSize, numbers.count)] })

Comment: which is now void with the new XC 7 Beta 6

Answer (score 56):

In Swift 3/4 this would look like the following:

```swift
let numbers = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7"]
let chunkSize = 2
let chunks = stride(from: 0, to: numbers.count, by: chunkSize).map {
    Array(numbers[$0..<min($0 + chunkSize, numbers.count)])
}
// prints as [["1", "2"], ["3", "4"], ["5", "6"], ["7"]]
```

As an extension to Array:

```
extension Array {
    func chunked(by chunkSize: Int) -> [[Element]] {
        return stride(from: 0, to: self.count, by: chunkSize).map {
            Array(self[$0..<Swift.min($0 + chunkSize, self.count)])
        }
    }
}
```

Or the slightly more verbose, yet more general:

```swift
let numbers = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7"]
let chunkSize = 2
let chunks: [[String]] = stride(from: 0, to: numbers.count, by: chunkSize).map {
    let end = numbers.endIndex
    let chunkEnd = numbers.index($0, offsetBy: chunkSize, limitedBy: end) ?? end
    return Array(numbers[$0..<chunkEnd])
}
```

This is more general because I am making fewer assumptions about the type of the index into the collection. In the previous implementation I assumed that they could be could be compared and added.

Note that in Swift 3 the functionality of advancing indices has been transferred from the indices themselves to the collection.

Comment: Could use ArraySlice as its more efficient i.e.
`func chunked(by chunkSize: Int) -> [ArraySlice<Element>]` then subtract the `Array( ... )` cast

Comment: How to edit the extension, to make chunked arrays with different size ? For example the first array to contain 17 and the other arrays to contain 25 ?

Answer (score 45):

With Swift 5, according to your needs, you can choose one of the **five following ways** in order to solve your problem.

---

### 1. Using `AnyIterator` in a `Collection` extension method

[`AnyIterator`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/anyiterator) is a good candidate to iterate over the indices of an object that conforms to `Collection` protocol in order to return subsequences of this object. In a `Collection` protocol extension, you can declare a `chunked(by:)` method with the following implementation:

```
extension Collection {
    
    func chunked(by distance: Int) -> [[Element]] {
        precondition(distance > 0, "distance must be greater than 0") // prevents infinite loop

        var index = startIndex
        let iterator: AnyIterator<Array<Element>> = AnyIterator({
            let newIndex = self.index(index, offsetBy: distance, limitedBy: self.endIndex) ?? self.endIndex
            defer { index = newIndex }
            let range = index ..< newIndex
            return index != self.endIndex ? Array(self[range]) : nil
        })
        
        return Array(iterator)
    }
    
}
```

Usage:

```
let array = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
let newArray = array.chunked(by: 2)
print(newArray) // prints: [["1", "2"], ["3", "4"], ["5", "6"], ["7", "8"], ["9"]]
```

---

### 2. Using `stride(from:to:by:)` function in an `Array` extension method

`Array` indices are of type `Int` and conform to `Strideable` protocol. Therefore, you can use [`stride(from:to:by:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1641347-stride) and [`advanced(by:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/int/1641594-advanced) with them. In an `Array` extension, you can declare a `chunked(by:)` method with the following implementation:

```
extension Array {
    
    func chunked(by distance: Int) -> [[Element]] {
        let indicesSequence = stride(from: startIndex, to: endIndex, by: distance)
        let array: [[Element]] = indicesSequence.map {
            let newIndex = $0.advanced(by: distance) > endIndex ? endIndex : $0.advanced(by: distance)
            //let newIndex = self.index($0, offsetBy: distance, limitedBy: self.endIndex) ?? self.endIndex // also works
            return Array(self[$0 ..< newIndex])
        }
        return array
    }
    
}
```

Usage:

```
let array = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
let newArray = array.chunked(by: 2)
print(newArray) // prints: [["1", "2"], ["3", "4"], ["5", "6"], ["7", "8"], ["9"]]
```

---

### 3. Using a recursive approach in an `Array` extension method

Based on Nate Cook [recursive code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26396000/1966109), you can declare a `chunked(by:)` method in an `Array` extension with the following implementation:

```
extension Array {

    func chunked(by distance: Int) -> [[Element]] {
        precondition(distance > 0, "distance must be greater than 0") // prevents infinite loop

        if self.count <= distance {
            return [self]
        } else {
            let head = [Array(self[0 ..< distance])]
            let tail = Array(self[distance ..< self.count])
            return head + tail.chunked(by: distance)
        }
    }
    
}
```

Usage:

```
let array = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
let newArray = array.chunked(by: 2)
print(newArray) // prints: [["1", "2"], ["3", "4"], ["5", "6"], ["7", "8"], ["9"]]
```

---

### 4. Using a for loop and batches in a `Collection` extension method

Chris Eidhof and Florian Kugler show in [Swift Talk #33 - Sequence & Iterator (Collections #2)](https://talk.objc.io/episodes/S01E33-sequence-iterator-collections-2) video how to use a simple for loop to fill batches of sequence elements and append them on completion to an array. In a `Sequence` extension, you can declare a `chunked(by:)` method with the following implementation:

```
extension Collection {
    
    func chunked(by distance: Int) -> [[Element]] {
        var result: [[Element]] = []
        var batch: [Element] = []
        
        for element in self {
            batch.append(element)
            
            if batch.count == distance {
                result.append(batch)
                batch = []
            }
        }
        
        if !batch.isEmpty {
            result.append(batch)
        }
        
        return result
    }
    
}
```

Usage:

```
let array = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
let newArray = array.chunked(by: 2)
print(newArray) // prints: [["1", "2"], ["3", "4"], ["5", "6"], ["7", "8"], ["9"]]
```

---

### 5. Using a custom `struct` that conforms to `Sequence` and `IteratorProtocol` protocols

If you don't want to create extensions of `Sequence`, `Collection` or `Array`, you can create a custom `struct` that conforms to `Sequence` and `IteratorProtocol` protocols. This `struct` should have the following implementation:

```
struct BatchSequence<T>: Sequence, IteratorProtocol {
    
    private let array: [T]
    private let distance: Int
    private var index = 0
    
    init(array: [T], distance: Int) {
        precondition(distance > 0, "distance must be greater than 0") // prevents infinite loop
        self.array = array
        self.distance = distance
    }
    
    mutating func next() -> [T]? {
        guard index < array.endIndex else { return nil }
        let newIndex = index.advanced(by: distance) > array.endIndex ? array.endIndex : index.advanced(by: distance)
        defer { index = newIndex }
        return Array(array[index ..< newIndex])
    }
    
}
```

Usage:

```
let array = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
let batchSequence = BatchSequence(array: array, distance: 2)
let newArray = Array(batchSequence)
print(newArray) // prints: [["1", "2"], ["3", "4"], ["5", "6"], ["7", "8"], ["9"]]
```

Comment: Hi, do you have the Swift 3 version of that extension method?

Comment: Great answer, thanks! Note that option 4 has what I consider odd behavior if the array being chunked is empty. It returns `[]` instead of `[[]]`. Option 3 behaves as I would expect.

Answer (score 9):

I like Nate Cook's answer, it looks like Swift has moved on since it was written, here's my take on this as an extension to Array:

```
extension Array {
    func chunk(chunkSize : Int) -> Array<Array<Element>> {
        return 0.stride(to: self.count, by: chunkSize)
            .map { Array(self[$0..<$0.advancedBy(chunkSize, limit: self.count)]) }
    }
}
```

Note, it returns [] for negative numbers and will result in a fatal error as written above. You'll have to put a guard in if you want to prevent that.

```
func testChunkByTwo() {
    let input = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
    let output = input.chunk(2)
    let expectedOutput = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6], [7]]
    XCTAssertEqual(expectedOutput, output)
}

func testByOne() {
    let input = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
    let output = input.chunk(1)
    let expectedOutput = [[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7]]
    XCTAssertEqual(expectedOutput, output)
}

func testNegative() {
    let input = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
    let output = input.chunk(-2)
    let expectedOutput = []
    XCTAssertEqual(expectedOutput, output)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you'll want to use map or reduce. Map is for applying a function on each individual element in an array while reduce is for flattening an array. What you want to do is slice the array into subarrays of a certain size. This snippet uses slices.

```
var arr = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7"]
var splitSize = 2

var newArr = [[String]]()
var i = 0
while i < arr.count {
    var slice: Slice<String>!
    if i + splitSize >= arr.count {
        slice = arr[i..<arr.count]
    }
    else {
        slice = arr[i..<i+splitSize]
    }
    newArr.append(Array(slice))
    i += slice.count
}
println(newArr)
```

Comment: This solution works in swift 2.2 until 3.0 which is a plus! And id argue that its  more readable until we all learn the latest flavour of 'new-speak'..I mean swift.

Answer (score 4):

Would be nice to express [Tyler Cloutier's formulation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38156873/341994) as an extension on Array:

```
extension Array {
    func chunked(by chunkSize:Int) -> [[Element]] {
        let groups = stride(from: 0, to: self.count, by: chunkSize).map {
            Array(self[$0..<[$0 + chunkSize, self.count].min()!])
        }
        return groups
    }
}
```

This gives us a general way to partition an array into chunks.

Comment: `Swift.min($0 + chunkSize, self.count)` instead of having to create an array

Answer (score 4):

New in Swift 4, you can do this efficiently with `reduce(into:)`. Here's an extension on Sequence:

```
extension Sequence {
    func eachSlice(_ clump:Int) -> [[Self.Element]] {
        return self.reduce(into:[]) { memo, cur in
            if memo.count == 0 {
                return memo.append([cur])
            }
            if memo.last!.count < clump {
                memo.append(memo.removeLast() + [cur])
            } else {
                memo.append([cur])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let result = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9].eachSlice(2)
// [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9]]
```

Answer (score 3):

The above is very cleaver, but it makes my head hurt. I had to revert back to a less swifty approach.

For Swift 2.0

```
var chunks = [[Int]]()
var temp = [Int]()
var splitSize = 3

var x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

for (i, element) in x.enumerate() {

    if temp.count < splitSize {
        temp.append(element)
    }
    if temp.count == splitSize {
        chunks.append(temp)
        temp.removeAll()
    }
}

if !temp.isEmpty {
    chunks.append(temp)
}
```

**`Playground Result [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7]]`**

Answer (score 3):

I'll just throw my hat in the ring here with another implementation based on `AnyGenerator.`

```
extension Array {
    func chunks(_ size: Int) -> AnyIterator<[Element]> {
        if size == 0 {
            return AnyIterator {
                return nil
            }
        }

        let indices = stride(from: startIndex, to: count, by: size)
        var generator = indices.makeIterator()

        return AnyIterator {
            guard let i = generator.next() else {
                return nil
            }

            var j = self.index(i, offsetBy: size)
            repeat {
                j = self.index(before: j)
            } while j >= self.endIndex

            return self[i...j].lazy.map { $0 }
        }
    }
}
```

I prefer this method since it relies exclusively on generators which can have a non-negligible, positive memory impact when dealing with large arrays.

For your specific example, here's how it would work:

```
let chunks = Array(["1","2","3","4","5","6","7"].chunks(2))
```

Result:

```
[["1", "2"], ["3", "4"], ["5", "6"], ["7"]]
```

Answer (score 3):

In Swift 4 or later you can also extend `Collection` and return a collection of `SubSequence` of it to be able to use it also with `StringProtocol` types (`String` or `Substring`). This way it will return a collection of substrings instead of a collection of a bunch of characters:

**Xcode 10.1 • Swift 4.2.1 or later**

```
extension Collection {
    func subSequences(limitedTo maxLength: Int) -> [SubSequence] {
        precondition(maxLength > 0, "groups must be greater than zero")
        var start = startIndex
        var subSequences: [SubSequence] = []
        while start < endIndex {
            let end = index(start, offsetBy: maxLength, limitedBy: endIndex) ?? endIndex
            defer { start = end }
            subSequences.append(self[start..<end])
        }
        return subSequences
    }
}
```

---

Or as suggested in comments by @Jessy using collection method

```
public func sequence<T, State>(state: State, next: @escaping (inout State) -> T?) -> UnfoldSequence<T, State>
```

---

```
extension Collection {
    func subSequences(limitedTo maxLength: Int) -> [SubSequence] {
        precondition(maxLength > 0, "groups must be greater than zero")
        return .init(sequence(state: startIndex) { start in
            guard start < self.endIndex else { return nil }
            let end = self.index(start, offsetBy: maxLength, limitedBy: self.endIndex) ?? self.endIndex
            defer { start = end }
            return self[start..<end]
        })
    }
}
```

Usage

```
let array = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
let slices = array.subSequences(limitedTo: 2)  // [ArraySlice(["1", "2"]), ArraySlice(["3", "4"]), ArraySlice(["5", "6"]), ArraySlice(["7", "8"]), ArraySlice(["9"])]
for slice in slices {
    print(slice) // prints: [["1", "2"], ["3", "4"], ["5", "6"], ["7", "8"], ["9"]]
}
// To convert from ArraySlice<Element> to Array<element>
let arrays = slices.map(Array.init)  // [["1", "2"], ["3", "4"], ["5", "6"], ["7", "8"], ["9"]]
```

---

---

```
extension Collection {
    var singles: [SubSequence] { return subSequences(limitedTo: 1) }
    var pairs:   [SubSequence] { return subSequences(limitedTo: 2) }
    var triples: [SubSequence] { return subSequences(limitedTo: 3) }
    var quads:   [SubSequence] { return subSequences(limitedTo: 4) }
}
```

---

Array or ArraySlice of Characters

```
let chars = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i"]
chars.singles  // [["a"], ["b"], ["c"], ["d"], ["e"], ["f"], ["g"], ["h"], ["i"]]
chars.pairs    // [["a", "b"], ["c", "d"], ["e", "f"], ["g", "h"], ["i"]]
chars.triples  // [["a", "b", "c"], ["d", "e", "f"], ["g", "h", "i"]]
chars.quads    // [["a", "b", "c", "d"], ["e", "f", "g", "h"], ["i"]]
chars.dropFirst(2).quads  // [["c", "d", "e", "f"], ["g", "h", "i"]]
```

---

StringProtocol Elements (String and SubString)

```
let str = "abcdefghi"
str.singles  // ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i"]
str.pairs    // ["ab", "cd", "ef", "gh", "i"]
str.triples  // ["abc", "def", "ghi"]
str.quads    // ["abcd", "efgh", "i"]
str.dropFirst(2).quads    // ["cdef", "ghi"]
```

Comment: This was a great idea! But `count` might be O(n), so it’s best to find some other way of iterating. I put one in my answer.

Comment: @Jessy you can simply use a while loop

Comment: No, then you’d have to pick a collection type to return, instead of just providing the sub-sequences as a sequence.

Comment: Well I would love to see the benchmark results on this one

Comment: @Jessy I have edit my answer as you suggested. Is there any problem with this approach?

Comment: The drawback with returning an array is that you lose the benefit of the lazy evaluation of the `UnfoldSequence`. But if that's what you really want, you can get rid of the wrapping `.init()` and change your last lines to `return [start..<end]` and `} .map { self[$0] }`.

Comment: @Jessy  sorry I did not understand what you meant

Comment: Sorry, typo. I meant  `return startIndex..<endIndex`, with no brackets.

Comment: @Jessy thats what I though you meant at first but don't know why when I first tried it resulted in empty collections. Why is this map approach faster than initializing a new collection with the resulting unfolded sequence?

Comment: It's not about speed; it's about chaining being less ugly than initializers, which increase the doom pyramid indentation by one level.

Comment: Well you have used  init on both of your extensions as well a subscript which I think is a very unintuitive.  I think the trailing syntax of the computed properties is much better and easier to write.

Answer (score 3):

## Swift 5.1 - General solution for all kind of Collections:

```
extension Collection where Index == Int {
    func chunked(by chunkSize: Int) -> [[Element]] {
        stride(from: startIndex, to: endIndex, by: chunkSize).map { Array(self[$0..<Swift.min($0 + chunkSize, count)]) }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not generic. It requires that the collection is indexed by an Int

Answer (score 0):

Do you know that any solution with [a...b] swift style works 10 times slower then regular?

```
for y in 0..<rows {
    var row = [Double]()
    for x in 0..<cols {
        row.append(stream[y * cols + x])
    }
    mat.append(row)
}
```

Try it and will see, here is my raw code for test:

```
let count = 1000000
let cols = 1000
let rows = count / cols
var stream = [Double].init(repeating: 0.5, count: count)

// Regular
var mat = [[Double]]()

let t1 = Date()

for y in 0..<rows {
    var row = [Double]()
    for x in 0..<cols {
        row.append(stream[y * cols + x])
    }
    mat.append(row)
}

print("regular: \(Date().timeIntervalSince(t1))")


//Swift
let t2 = Date()

var mat2: [[Double]] = stride(from: 0, to: stream.count, by: cols).map {
    let end = stream.endIndex
    let chunkEnd = stream.index($0, offsetBy: cols, limitedBy: end) ?? end
    return Array(stream[$0..<chunkEnd])
}

print("swift: \(Date().timeIntervalSince(t2))")
```

and out:

regular: 0.0449600219726562

swift: 0.49255496263504

Comment: Let me guess. You are benchmarking this in a playground

Answer (score 0):

```swift
public extension Optional {
  /// Wraps a value in an `Optional`, based on a condition.
  /// - Parameters:
  ///   - wrapped: A non-optional value.
  ///   - getIsNil: The condition that will result in `nil`.
  init(
    _ wrapped: Wrapped,
    nilWhen getIsNil: (Wrapped) throws -> Bool
  ) rethrows {
    self = try getIsNil(wrapped) ? nil : wrapped
  }
}
```

```swift
public extension Sequence {
  /// Splits a `Sequence` into equal "chunks".
  ///
  /// - Parameter maxArrayCount: The maximum number of elements in a chunk.
  /// - Returns: `Array`s with `maxArrayCount` `counts`,
  ///   until the last chunk, which may be smaller.
  subscript(maxArrayCount maxCount: Int) -> AnySequence<[Element]> {
    .init(
      sequence( state: makeIterator() ) { iterator in
        Optional(
          (0..<maxCount).compactMap { _ in iterator.next() },
          nilWhen: \.isEmpty
        )
      }
    )
  }
}
```

```swift
// [ ["1", "2"], ["3", "4"], ["5", "6"], ["7"] ]"
(1...7).map(String.init)[maxArrayCount: 2]
```

```
public extension Collection {
  /// Splits a `Collection` into equal "chunks".
  ///
  /// - Parameter maxSubSequenceCount: The maximum number of elements in a chunk.
  /// - Returns: `SubSequence`s with `maxSubSequenceLength` `counts`,
  ///   until the last chunk, which may be smaller.
  subscript(maxSubSequenceCount maxCount: Int) -> AnySequence<SubSequence> {
    .init(
      sequence(state: startIndex) { startIndex in
        guard startIndex < self.endIndex
        else { return nil }

        let endIndex =
          self.index(startIndex, offsetBy: maxCount, limitedBy: self.endIndex)
          ?? self.endIndex
        defer { startIndex = endIndex }
        return self[startIndex..<endIndex]
      }
    )
  }
}
```

```swift
// ["12", "34", "56", "7"]
(1...7).map(String.init).joined()[maxSubSequenceCount: 2]
```