# Swift - array of strings to multiple subarrays with constant number of strings

Tags: arrays, swift

Let's say I have this array of strings:

```
let Vehicles = ["Aeroplane", "Bicycle", "CarVehicle", "Lorry", "Motorbike", "Scooter", "Ship", "Train"]
```

What I want is this result:

```
let resultArray = [["Aeroplane", "Bicycle", "CarVehicle", "Lorry"], ["Motorbike", "Scooter", "Ship", "Train"]]
```

I know I could do this by `for` but I want to use Higher Order functions in Swift. I mean functions like map, reduce, filter. I think it's possible to do this way and it could be better. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks

Comment: See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33540708/1966109) to a very similar question that offers up to 5 different ways to solve your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A possible solution with `map()` and `stride()`:

```
let vehicles = ["Aeroplane", "Bicycle", "CarVehicle", "Lorry", "Motorbike", "Scooter", "Ship", "Train"]
let each = 4

let resultArray = map(stride(from: 0, to: vehicles.count, by: each)) {
    vehicles[$0 ..< advance($0, each, vehicles.count)]
}

println(resultArray)
// [[Aeroplane, Bicycle, CarVehicle, Lorry], [Motorbike, Scooter, Ship, Train]]
```

The usage of `advance()` in the closure guarantees that the code
works even if the number of array elements is not a multiple of 4
(and the last subarray in the result will then be shorter.)

You can simplify it to

```
let resultArray = map(stride(from: 0, to: vehicles.count, by: each)) {
    vehicles[$0 ..< $0 + each]
}
```

if you *know* that the number of array elements is a multiple of 4.

Strictly speaking the elements of `resultArray` are not arrays
but array slices. In many cases that does not matter, otherwise you
can replace it by

```
let resultArray = map(stride(from: 0, to: vehicles.count, by: each)) {
    Array(vehicles[$0 ..< advance($0, each, vehicles.count)])
}
```

Comment: Looks like what I was looking for. I forget mention that number of elements don't need to be multiple of 4 so thanks for first solution. One more thing. I have problem that I have result as `ArraySlice<String>` not `[String]`. How can I fix it?

Comment: @MartinR Would it also be possible to do it with `reduce` and `map` together?

Comment: @JacobsonTalom: It would be possible with `reduce()`, but then a "nested array" would be created in each call of the reduce closure, so that is probably less effective. Of course there might be another solution that I did not think of.