# Using Stride in Swift 2.0

Tags: swift, sequence, stride

I'm trying to figure out how to use the Stride features in Swift.

It seems to have changed again, since Xcode 7.0 beta 6.

Previously I could use

```
let strideAmount = stride(from: 0, to: items.count, by: splitSize)
let sets = strideAmount.map({ clients[$0..<advance($0, splitSize, items.count)] })
```

Now, despite the code hint I cannot figure out how to use this feature.

Any examples would be helpful thanks.

I've looked at [examples](http://ericasadun.com/2015/05/21/swift-six-killer-features/), but I cannot come to grips with how to use it. All I get from the Apple Docs are limited.

Thanks

Comment: stride is used for generating one number for inner function, so it can't be simply used for splicing arrays because you need to numbers(start & end indexes) for that

Comment: @maxpovver so using it for this is a bad idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26395766/swift-what-is-the-right-way-to-split-up-a-string-resulting-in-a-string-wi

Comment: it's up to you @DogCoffee

Comment: The others make my head hurt - I've added my KISS approach.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

It changed a bit, here is the new syntax:

```
0.stride(to: 10, by: 2)
```

and

```
Array(0.stride(to: 10, by: 2)) // is [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
```

if you take a look at [here](http://swiftdoc.org/swift-2/protocol/Strideable/hierarchy/), you can see what types conform to the `Strideable` protocol.

As @RichFox pointed out, in Swift 3.0 the syntax changed back to the original global function form like:

```
stride(from:0, to: 10, by: 2)
```

Comment: I did not know of SwiftDoc - bonus! Thanks

Comment: syntax is now global function again... 
`stride(from:0, to: 10, by: 2)` for example you can :
`for i in stride(from:0, to: 10, by: 2) { print(i) }`

Comment: `let array = Array(1...10)` or `let array = Array(1..<10)`, @DánielNagy I just want to know the advantages of stride while we can use closed rages and open ranges like I mentioned here.

Comment: @abhi1992 I did not checked it before, but I think the constructor which you described was added in Swift 3 as well. IMO using `stride` makes sense only if you are not creating a sequence with consecutive elements, otherwise I would use `Array(1...10)` since it's shorter.

Answer (score 1):

**Usage of stride function in swift 4.2**

```
12345
 2345
  345
   45
    5
    5
   45
  345
 2345
12345


for i in 1...5{
    for k in 1...i{
        print(terminator : " ")
    }
    for j in stride(from: i, to: 6, by: 1){
        print(j , terminator : "")
    }

    print(" ")
}
for i in stride(from: 5, to: 0, by: -1)
{
    for k in 1...i{
        print(terminator : " ")
    }
    for j in stride(from: i, to: 6, by: 1){
        print(j,terminator : "")
    }
    print(" ")
}
1 2 3 4 5
 2 3 4 5
  3 4 5
   4 5
    5
    5
   4 5
  3 4 5
 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5
for i in 1...5{
    for k in 0...i{
        print(terminator : " ")
    }
    for j in stride(from: i, to: 6, by: 1){
        print(j , terminator : " ")
    }

    print(" ")
}

for i in stride(from: 6, to: 1, by: -1){
    for k in 1...i{
        print(terminator : " ")
    }
    for j in stride(from: i-1, to: 6, by: 1){
        print(j , terminator : " ")
    }

    print(" ")
}
```