# How can I do a Swift for-in loop with a step?

Tags: swift

With the [removal of the traditional C-style for-loop in Swift 3.0](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0007-remove-c-style-for-loops.md), how can I do the following?

```
for (i = 1; i < max; i+=2) {
    // Do something
}
```

In Python, the for-in control flow statement has an optional step value:

```
for i in range(1, max, 2):
    # Do something
```

But the Swift range operator appears to have no equivalent:

```
for i in 1..<max {
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35032182/swift-c-style-loops-deprecated-decrement-index.

Comment: I didn't see that one! I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32197250/using-stride-in-swift-2-0) which led me to my answer. The keyword I was missing when I was searching (before asking the question) was "stride" - I was using the term "step" and not finding any useful results. Then when I found stride, I found Erica Sadun's [post on the topic](http://ericasadun.com/2015/05/21/swift-six-killer-features/) which is now out of date.

Comment: I think this should be reopened. The "for loop with a step/interval" is a specific question and has the unique answer of `Stride` in Swift, which is different than the dupe Question.

Answer (score 165, accepted):

The Swift synonym for a "step" is "stride" - the [Strideable protocol](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/strideable) in fact, implemented by [many common numerical types](http://swiftdoc.org/v2.1/protocol/Strideable/hierarchy/).

The equivalent of `(i = 1; i < max; i+=2)` is:

```
for i in stride(from: 1, to: max, by: 2) {
    // Do something
}
```

Alternatively, to get the equivalent of `i<=max`, use the `through` variant:

```
for i in stride(from: 1, through: max, by: 2) {
    // Do something
}
```

Note that `stride` returns a [`StrideTo`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/strideto)/[`StrideThrough`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/stridethrough), which conforms to [`Sequence`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence), so anything you can do with a sequence, you can do with the result of a call to `stride` (ie `map`, `forEach`, `filter`, etc). For example:

```
stride(from: 1, to: max, by: 2).forEach { i in
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: in swift 3 you can use the global functions `stride(from:through:by:)` and `stride(from:to:by:)`
like `for i in stride(from:1, to:max, by:2){...}`

Comment: @MarkoNikolovski please don't add code to other users' answers.  We don't want to put words in their mouth.  Instead, add a new answer.  Since this question is closed, you can add a new answer to the linked duplicate.