# Separate Strings from Array for HTML use in Xcode 7 Swift 2

Tags: html, arrays, string, swift2, xcode7.1

I'm using Xcode 7.1 and Swift 2. I have an `array` `var ingredientsList: [String] = []` that will contain data that is displayed in a `UITableView`.  I want to separate each `String` in the `array` and assign to a new `string` variable to later add to some `html`.  I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26395766/swift-what-is-the-right-way-to-split-up-a-string-resulting-in-a-string-wi) and it was very confusing and also dealt with `int`.  I tried to apply it with mine, but obviously using `string` instead but it didn't work.  Can someone please help me? An example of the array data is: `cheese, pepperoni, sauce, olives, onions, sausage`. Thank you.

My `ViewController` with a `UITableView` is:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cellIdentifier = "IngredientTableViewCell"

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! IngredientTableViewCell

    cell.ingredientLabel.text = ingredientsList[indexPath.row]

    // TOTAL of 50 ingredients Max
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        if ingredientsList[0] != "" {
            ingredientItem0 = ingredientsList[0]
        }
    }
    if indexPath.row == 1 {
        if ingredientsList[1] != "" {
            ingredientItem1 = ingredientsList[1]
        }
    }
    if indexPath.row == 2 {
        if ingredientsList[2] != "" {
            ingredientItem2 = ingredientsList[2]
        }
    }
    if indexPath.row == 3 {
        if ingredientsList[3] != "" {
            ingredientItem3 = ingredientsList[3]
        }
    }
    if indexPath.row == 4 {
        if ingredientsList[4] != "" {
            ingredientItem4 = ingredientsList[4]
        }
    }
    if indexPath.row == 5 {
        if ingredientsList[5] != "" {
            ingredientItem5 = ingredientsList[5]
        }
    }

    // ... it goes all the way down to a total of 50 ingredients

    return cell

}
```

I have a `UIBarButtonItem` that performs an action of exporting the `[String]` data as a PDF and allows the user to email it out.

My export code is:

```
    let html =
    /*HEADING*/"<head><center><br><h1><b>** <u>\(nameTextField.text!)</b></u> **</h1></br></center></head>" +
    /*DIVIDER*/"<center>- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -</center>" +
    /*BODY*/"<p><font size=5><br>\(ingredientItem0)</br> <br>\(ingredientItem1)</br> <br>\(ingredientItem2)</br> <br>\(ingredientItem3)</br> <br>\(ingredientItem4)</br> <br>\(ingredientItem5)</br> ... <br>\(ingredientItem49)</br></font></p>"

    let fmt = UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter(markupText: html)

    // Assign print formatter to UIPrintPageRenderer

    let render = UIPrintPageRenderer()
    render.addPrintFormatter(fmt, startingAtPageAtIndex: 0)

    // Assign paperRect and printableRect

    let page = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 595.2, height: 841.8) // A4, 72 dpi
    let printable = CGRectInset(page, 0, 0)

    render.setValue(NSValue(CGRect: page), forKey: "paperRect")
    render.setValue(NSValue(CGRect: printable), forKey: "printableRect")

    // Create PDF context and draw

    let pdfData = NSMutableData()
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, CGRectZero, nil)

    for i in 1...render.numberOfPages() {

        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
        let bounds = UIGraphicsGetPDFContextBounds()
        render.drawPageAtIndex(i - 1, inRect: bounds)
    }

    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
```

Right now, in my `UITableView` code above, I have it assign each `indexPath.row` to a `String` `variable` I've created.  I have it set for up to 50 ingredients.  I don't like that I've set a limit and if the user only has 4 ingredients and or more than 50. In my pdf export, it acts like there are 50 and prints blank lines for them.  So a potentially short recipe will have blank pages from the blank ingredients that I assigned that weren't there. Make sense?  It's ugly, but I don't know how else to do it.

Comment: Can you add a snippet of code?

Comment: Please see edit above.  It's ugly on some parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For loop through your ingredients list in your export code and append your html that wraps your ingredient list item to the html

```
 var html =
/*HEADING*/"<head><center><br><h1><b>** <u>\(nameTextField.text!)</b></u> **</h1></br></center></head>" +
/*DIVIDER*/"<center>- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -</center>" +
/*BODY*/"<p><font size=5>"

 for var i = 0; i < ingredientsList.length; i++ {
    html += "<br>\(ingredientsList[i] as String)</br> "
 }
```

Something like that....

Comment: I did a little tweaking but it works perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: @ChallengerGuy nice glad to be of assistance