# Putting the count of a loop in an array index

Tags: arrays, swift

Hello am new to SO and i need some help. Is there a way i can put the value of count of  a loop as an index for this:

```
var groups = [[String]]()

groupA.append(arr[randoms[0]])
groupA.append(arr[randoms[1]])

groupB.append(arr[randoms[2]])
groupB.append(arr[randoms[3]])

groupC.append(arr[randoms[4]])
groupC.append(arr[randoms[5]])

groupD.append(arr[randoms[6]])
groupD.append(arr[randoms[7]])

groupE.append(arr[randoms[8]])
groupE.append(arr[randoms[9]])

groups.append(groupA)
groups.append(groupB)
groups.append(groupC)
groups.append(groupD)
groups.append(groupE)
```

i want the index 0-10 of the random array to be from a loop or be dynamic in some way is there a way i can achieve this with swift?

Comment: Why do you need `randoms` at all? Just generate the random numbers.

Comment: I generated random number that won't repeat the same number and stored it in an array

Comment: Yes, I thought maybe that was the reason. :)

Comment: In that case, why not just shuffle `arr`? Now the first 10 items of the shuffled array are your items to be dealt out into groups.

Comment: After shuffling all the items how can i group it then? because am using a multidimensional array here

Comment: I don't see any multidimensional array in your code. Basically you need to show your real code, I think.

Comment: So am I right that you never really needed `groupA` and `groupB` etc in the first place? You really just want to form (or deal into) this array of arrays? Because this is actually going to be much more feasible if you don't have these extra copies of the arrays.

Comment: Yes i want to pair the elements of the array

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: I would suggest that, at bottom, this is just a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26395766/swift-what-is-the-right-way-to-split-up-a-string-resulting-in-a-string-wi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be looking for this sort of thing. Let's get rid of `random` and just *shuffle* `arr` to generate a list of actual values in random order. (There's lots of array-shuffling code on Stack Overflow so I won't bother to tell you how to do that.) Then we can also get rid of your intermediate arrays and just deal directly into the inner arrays of the array-of-arrays `groups`:

```
var groups : [[String]] = Array(repeating: [], count: 5)
var shuffled = ["hey", "ho", "nonny", "no", "sis", "boom", "bah", "yo", "hi", "lo"]

var next = 0
for ix in stride(from:0, to:9, by:2) {
    for ixx in 0..<2 {
        groups[next].append(shuffled[ix+ixx])
    }
    next += 1
}

groups // [["hey", "ho"], ["nonny", "no"], ["sis", "boom"], ["bah", "yo"], ["hi", "lo"]]
```

We can actually express that more concisely using `map` (as explained [Swift: what is the right way to split up a [String] resulting in a [[String]] with a given subarray size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26395766/swift-what-is-the-right-way-to-split-up-a-string-resulting-in-a-string-wi)):

```
let shuffled = ["hey", "ho", "nonny", "no", "sis", "boom", "bah", "yo", "hi", "lo"]
let chunkSize = 2
let groups = stride(from: 0, to: shuffled.count, by: chunkSize).map {
    Array(shuffled[$0..<min($0 + chunkSize, shuffled.count)])
}

groups // [["hey", "ho"], ["nonny", "no"], ["sis", "boom"], ["bah", "yo"], ["hi", "lo"]]
```

Even better, we can make this an extension on Array:

```
extension Array {
    func chunked(by chunkSize:Int) -> [[Element]] {
        let groups = stride(from: 0, to: self.count, by: chunkSize).map {
            Array(self[$0..<[$0 + chunkSize, self.count].min()!])
        }
        return groups
    }
}


let shuffled = ["hey", "ho", "nonny", "no", "sis", "boom", "bah", "yo", "hi", "lo"]
let groups = shuffled.chunked(by:2)

groups // [["hey", "ho"], ["nonny", "no"], ["sis", "boom"], ["bah", "yo"], ["hi", "lo"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the `enumerated()` function...

```
import Foundation
let randoms = [arc4random(),arc4random(),arc4random(),arc4random(),]
randoms.enumerated().forEach {
    print($0,$1)
}
```

Try that out in an Xcode Playground.

Comment: This did not work and how am i supposed to use it with my code?

Comment: Don't forget to `import Foundation`

Comment: Hafeez Sagay, I'm just trying to show you how to incorporate the index of an item in an array into a loop.