# Split Sequence/Collection Into Chunks

Tags: arrays, swift, string, generics, collections

Paul Hudson explained how to split a Swift `Array` into chunks in [his article](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/how-to-split-an-array-into-chunks). It works like this:

```swift
extension Array {
    func chunked(into size: Int) -> [[Element]] {
        return stride(from: 0, to: count, by: size).map {
            Array(self[$0 ..< Swift.min($0 + size, count)])
        }
    }
}
```

and can be used like this:

```
let numbers = Array(1...100)
let result = numbers.chunked(into: 5)
```

I wonder if this algorithm could be generalized to make it work for arbitrary collections/sequences, especially `String`s. I thought about applying this algorithm to to the protocols `Collection` or `Sequence`...

Any ideas?

Comment: For collections: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33540708/1187415. For  sequences: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46141693/1187415

Comment: Done already here https://stackoverflow.com/a/54524110/2303865

Comment: @MartinR those would return `[[Element]]` instead of `[SubSequence]`

Comment: Yeah thank's so much! Exactly what I searched for! Didn't find those answers somehow 