# How can I join every 8 item of array and create 1 item?

Tags: arrays, swift

I want to get together every 8 item in array and create 1 item (I want to get 0...8, 9,...17 etc and make these one string.) Let me say more clear I have this array :

```
["ALINMA Bostancı - Yan Yol - Yan apt no:4 - Kadıköy - 7 - 23 - 29.103910631539957 - 40.96400403065958", "TESLIM Bostancı - Yan Yol - Yan apt no:4 - Kadıköy - 7 - 23 - 29.103910631539957 - 40.96400403065958", "10:00 - 11:00", "19/11/2019", "18:00 - 19:00", "21/11/2019", "Tshirt = 4", "Testçi", "ALINMA Bostancı - Yan Yol - Yan apt no:4 - Kadıköy - 7 - 23 - 29.103910631539957 - 40.96400403065958", "TESLIM Bostancı - Yan Yol - Yan apt no:4 - Kadıköy - 7 - 23 - 29.103910631539957 - 40.96400403065958", "18:00 - 19:00", "22/11/2019", "", "27/11/2019", "Tshirt = 4 ; Sweatshirt = 3", "Testçi", "ALINMA 19 Mayıs - Bayar Caddesi - Knkk  - Kadıköy - Kjb - Bng - 29.088674699528724 - 40.975391102375454", "TESLIM 19 Mayıs - Mehpare Sokak - Dergah no:1  - Kadıköy - 4 - 14 - 29.088822539423138 - 40.97780621764736", "18:00 - 19:00", "20/11/2019", "10:00 - 11:00", "23/11/2019", "Tshirt = 1 ; Kaz tüyü mont = 2", "Mehmett"]
```

I want to make it like

```
["ALINMA Bostancı - Yan Yol - Yan apt no:4 - Kadıköy - 7 - 23 - 29.103910631539957 - 40.96400403065958 TESLIM Bostancı - Yan Yol - Yan apt no:4 - Kadıköy - 7 - 23 - 29.103910631539957 - 40.96400403065958  10:00 - 11:00  19/11/2019  18:00 - 19:00 21/11/2019 Tshirt = 4  Testçi", "ALINMA Bostancı - Yan Yol - Yan apt no:4 - Kadıköy - 7 - 23 - 29.103910631539957 - 40.96400403065958 TESLIM Bostancı - Yan Yol - Yan apt no:4 - Kadıköy - 7 - 23 - 29.103910631539957 - 40.96400403065958 18:00 - 19:00 22/11/2019   27/11/2019 Tshirt = 4 ; Sweatshirt = 3  Testçi", "ALINMA 19 Mayıs - Bayar Caddesi - Knkk  - Kadıköy - Kjb - Bng - 29.088674699528724 - 40.975391102375454 TESLIM 19 Mayıs - Mehpare Sokak - Dergah no:1  - Kadıköy - 4 - 14 - 29.088822539423138 - 40.97780621764736  18:00 - 19:00  20/11/2019  10:00 - 11:00  23/11/2019  Tshirt = 1 ; Kaz tüyü mont = 2  Mehmett"]
```

I have already tried joined() method but How can I give range of 8 element? Can you help me?

Comment: Can you provide a simpler example covering all your requirements?

Comment: So you want to grab element 0..7, 8...15, etc, and join those elements into one string? If so, check out Array.split()

Comment: The example array does not help. Please provide a simple example array

Comment: @OscarApeland actually I want to grab 0...8, 9...16, etc. ( I want to make it these 0...8 to one string element)

Comment: @swifty2 did you see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58971636/5623035)?

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini yes these two answers correct thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a part of the array and join it to string.

```
let datas = [YOUR_CURRENT_DATAS]
let firstItem = Array(datas[0..<8]).joined("")
let secondItem = Array(datas[8..<16]).joined("")
... 
// For dynamic datas you can loop the datas array
var newDatas: [String] = []
var i = 0
while (i < datas.count) {
    let item = Array(datas[i..<(i+8)]).joined(separator: "")
    newDatas.append(item)
    i += 8
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but my array counts will be dynamic so it will be change. I need some range operations like range<myarray.count> . How can I solve it?

Answer (score 2):

Using this little extension ([can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58973197/5623035)):

```
extension Collection where Index == Int {
    func chunked(by chunkSize: Int) -> [[Element]] {
        stride(from: startIndex, to: endIndex, by: chunkSize).map { Array(self[$0..<Swift.min($0 + chunkSize, count)]) }
    }
}
```

You can split your array into chunks of any size:

```
x.chunked(by: 8)
```

Then you can join each chunk:

```
x.chunked(by: 8).map{ $0.joined(separator: " ") }
```

<sub>`x` is used to demonstrate: `let x = (1...80).map{ String($0) }` but you should replace it with the actual array</sub>