# Split a large Vector Equally in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, coreml

I have a large MLMultiArray of length 15360 values.

Sample:

```
[14.78125,-0.6308594,5.609375,13.57812,-1.871094,-19.65625,9.5625,8.640625,-2.728516,3.654297,-3.189453,-1.740234...]
```

Is there a way I can convert this huge array into 120 small MLMultiArrays with 128 elements each without changing the sequence of this array and in the most efficient way possible?

The entire array of 15360 elements is available in this [Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UKwmuO0bRH20-i76Ss-bI_vUn8q1Tcit/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/how-to-split-an-array-into-chunks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26395766/swift-what-is-the-right-way-to-split-up-a-string-resulting-in-a-string-wi etc.

Comment: Maybe not slice it at all but instead accessing the array using an interval, n * 128 -> n +128 - 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, You can do this with an extension which you can also use it as a general solution:

```
extension Array {
    func splited(into size: Int) -> [[Element]] {
        return stride(from: 0, to: count, by: size).map {
            Array(self[$0 ..< Swift.min($0 + size, count)])
        }
    }
}
let yourArray = [14.78125,-0.6308594, ...] // 15360 elements of your array
let result = yourArray.splited(into: 128)
```

Comment: Is there a way I can do the same thing but for an MLMultiArray? instead of a Float32?