# Gridview in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, swift5

I'm trying to create a grid view in swiftui and it's not working out for me. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I tried using a c style for loop where I can set a variable and increment it, but swiftui throws an error when I do that.

```
struct ProductSubCat: View {

    @State var productCategory = String()
    @State var number = Int()
    @ObservedObject var allData = WebserviceGetDataSolutions()
    @State var theCount = 0



    var body: some View {

                ScrollView {
                    Spacer()

                    ForEach(0 ..< self.allData.posts[self.number].productLines.count / 2, id: \.self) {row in

                        HStack {
                            ForEach(0..<2) {cell in
                                NavigationLink(destination: ProductDetails())
                                {
                                    Text(self.allData.posts[self.number].productLines[row].system)

                                   Image("stonclad")
                                   .resizable()
                                   .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)



                                }.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())

                            }


                        }


                    }

        }   
        }

    }
```

Comment: please read and consider https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and you should (!) tell us what error appeared and in what line...

Comment: It helps a lot when example code is actually runnable - please replace things like 'WebserviceGetDataSolutions' with a simple struct.

Comment: Now you can use `LazyHGrid` and `LazyVGrid` after `swiftUI2.o` update in wwdc2o2o ... https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-position-views-in-a-grid-using-lazyvgrid-and-lazyhgrid

Answer (score 5):

Use an [Array extension to split the list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38156873/128083) into smaller groups of size:

```swift
extension Array {
    func chunks(_ size: Int) -> [[Element]] {
        stride(from: 0, to: self.count, by: size).map { ($0 ..< Swift.min($0 + size, self.count)).map { self[$0] } }
    }
}
```

This can then be used to create something like a simple grid View, for example:

```swift
struct Product: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String
}

struct SimpleGridViewExample: View {

    var products = [Product(name: "p1"), Product(name: "p2"), Product(name: "p3"), Product(name: "p4"), Product(name: "p5")]

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                ForEach(products.chunks(2), id: \.self) { chunk in
                    HStack {
                        ForEach(chunk, id: \.self) { product in
                            VStack {
                                Image(systemName: "sun.max")
                                    .resizable()
                                    .frame(maxWidth: 100, maxHeight: 100)
                                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                Text(product.name)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```